# Nautilus crashes, no desktop icons

Tags: nautilus, desktop-icons

I need your help,
when I launch Nautilus it crashes in 2 secons + desktop icons aren't displayed.
I tried to uninstall python-nautilus but it doesn't work for me + don't have any zero byte file.
Using terminal: Unauthorized access to memory SIGSEGV

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days trying fix it, I found the problem. Nautilus couldn't display .j2k file on desktop. When I deleted this .j2k file (which btw was not zero byte!) nautilus started working fine.
I wonder that .j2k is not supported!!!

Comment: Can you explain more how you fix it? I have similar problem, but cant find any .j2k file. Nautilus works fine if it's not selected the "show desktop icons" option, but if selected, nautilus immediately crashes. This is the error message running from terminal: The program 'nautilus' received an X Window System error. This probably reflects a bug in the program. The error was 'BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)'. (Details: serial 639 error_code 8 request_code 139 minor_code 4) (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously; that is, you will receive the error a while a

Comment: I'm just an ordinary PC user so I have only a few tips. Try to check if you haven't created an unusual file on desktop (I fixed it by chance - I deleted the .j2k file), try to launch nautilus in terminal with sudo rights (running _sudo nautilus_ it didn't crash immediately like in normal mode, crashed only when opened the directory with unsupported file so it worked as a diagnosis for me :D).